Bengali text not working inside array
I am using Bengali text as an option in a math question. My code is below:
\documentclass[margin=1mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\bengalifont}[Script=Bengali]{akaashnormal.ttf}

\begin{document} 
\textbengali{কেমন আছেন ?}
$\begin{array}{cccc}

\textbf{(A)} &  \textbengali{ স্বসম }  & \hspace{2in} \vspace{0.3cm} \textbf{(B)} &  \textbengali{প্রতিসম}  \\
    \textbf{(C)} &  \textbengali{সংক্রমণশীল}  & \hspace{2in} \textbf{(D)} & \textbengali{এদের কোনোটিই নয়।}

\end{array}$

\end{document}

But here "কেমন আছেন?" is compiled and gives output but inside the array those options that are in Bengali are not compiled or left blank, and no text is there, like the below picture

What do you think I should do? Because in my questions there are some options in Bengali...

I don't have your special fonts, so can't test myself, but maybe try \text{\textbengali{ স্বসম }} to switch back to text mode.

Since you're not typesetting any math-y material, there's no point in employing an array environment. Just use a tabular environment instead.

Since no math-y material is being typeset, I can't see a reason for employing an array environment. I'd use a tabular environment instead.
The following code uses the Noto Serif Bengali font since akaashnormal is not installed on my system.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}

%%\usepackage{fontspec} % 'polyglossia' automatically loads 'fontspec'
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\bengalifont}[Script=Bengali]{Noto Serif Bengali}

\begin{document} 

\textbengali{কেমন আছেন ?}\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{\hspace{1.5cm}} ll @{}}  % why '2in' spacing?
\textbf{(A)} & \textbengali{স্বসম }  &
   \textbf{(B)} & \textbengali{প্রতিসম}  \\
\textbf{(C)} & \textbengali{সংক্রমণশীল}  & 
   \textbf{(D)} & \textbengali{এদের কোনোটিই নয়।}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


I don't know why the text (A) and the others are in boldface but the Bengali texts are also in boldface

@zero_infinity - The labels (A), (B), etc are in boldface because of the \textbf directives, which i copied from the code in your query. Are you sure the Bengali text strings are in bold in the answer I provided?

I'm sorry, I was mistaken. When I made the picture bigger, it looked like all the text was bold.
